# How to create pills input fields in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, user-experience

I'm looking for a way to make "dynamic pills" like the ones below, but in React Native and Redux.
https://codepen.io/silkine/pen/pPxJOX

```
   <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="tim">this codepen is dedicated to
     <a href="https://twitter.com/twholman">@twholman</a> 
    </div>
```

1) Anyone know what they are called so it's easier to google tutorials?

2) I'm trying to convert the css with gulp and copy paste the JS into RN, but changing react syntax into RN. Getting a lot of errors. Is this a good path? Or do you know a simpler one? Maybe a tutorial somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's called Badge.
2. You can use UI Kit like [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements) or you can check out code of this element in [github](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/badge/badge.js) repo. Use 'children' prop to pass TextInput.

Comment: 1. Is the name still "badge" if users are supposed to input their own text in the symbol? 2) Thanks a lot for the link! Do you mean I can pass a TextInput prop as child to the Badge? (So users can input their own text.)

Comment: 1. I don't think there is a special name for a badge with input. 
2. Look on possible props you can pass to Badge component in this [table](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/badge/#badge-props). You can pass TextInput as a children prop.

Comment: You can also use the simple package I've made: https://github.com/krszwsk/react-native-badge-input